# Exclude an Endpoint when Transforming Server Typings

Tags: c#, typescript, typescript-typings, serenity-platform

How to exclude an Endpoint when Transforming Server Typings? Is there any attribute or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ScriptSkip] attribute